# how to send custom get HTTP request using c#?

Tags: c#, http

I want to send a request like this

```
GET /v1/contacts?sid=msgrsessionid
Authorization: OAuth
realm="yahooapis.com",
oauth_consumer_key="dj0yJmk9nM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD1lMg--",
oauth_nonce="24829.2331",
oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT",
oauth_timestamp="1219450170",
oauth_token="A%3DuqkiebGpiTJl7ThQxU.jDXXaETYyfEy3xAKPyoavokwOOcZcz8Xs_l1Nvnl._KmCEVCeLkxxT1Y6BgRqf5f98sQWHklBM_anetveR7okK_M_5XEmQ1_1reo3UgKQULT_dQT8Gao3rgz5rJxgmnYrhdWWdfgTdMQVzpbJT2aGkz59NTK1O8yXVE1EvZUCqju7WiFYu.WHNEw.9TWq3g--",
oauth_version="1.0",
oauth_signature="O2AQipLITO0aYHKZc9266RzC94%260af0ef7f79bfb89dd6af87589e4c97b022f594a3"
```

I'm using the code below,but I get Unauthorized access (401) exception,what is wrong here and how do I send the above raw request as a string (like what we do with telnet) not constructed as WebRequest.

```
Uri address = new Uri("https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_token");
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
StringBuilder authHeader = new StringBuilder();
authHeader.Append("Authorization: OAuth ");
authHeader.Append("realm=\"yahooapis.com\", ");
authHeader.Append("oauth_consumer_key=\""+consumerKey+"\", ");
authHeader.Append("oauth_nonce=\""+random+"\", ");
authHeader.Append("oauth_signature_method=\"PLAINTEXT\", ");
authHeader.Append("oauth_timestamp=\""+UnixTimeNow().ToString()+"\", ");
authHeader.Append("oauth_token=\""+requestToken.Trim()+"\", ");
authHeader.Append("oauth_version=\"1.0\", ");            
authHeader.Append("oauth_signature=\""+HttpUtility.UrlEncode(consumerKey+"&"+consumersecret)+"\"");

request.Headers.Add(authHeader.ToString());
```

Comment: What does your raw `WebRequest` request look like? (You can view raw headers in [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/))

Comment: Is there a reason that you're not using [OAuth libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997172/oauth-2-0-service-provider-net-libraries) to make the request instead of trying to put it together by hand?

Comment: I just need to get the hang of this for the rest of my project,I want to use yahoo apis,if I don't get this,I wont be able to do the rest

Answer (score 0):

If you want an API that gives you more control over the data you're sending over the wire, [you can roll your sleeves up a bit further and work with TcpClient instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx).

That said, it is not what I'd recommend - as I mentioned in a comment above, [there are .Net OAuth libraries out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997172/oauth-2-0-service-provider-net-libraries).  My experience with OAuth is passing at best (but enough to say with some confidence "if you solve this problem, you will run into another one and another one"), but unless your product is an OAuth library itself, I've got no idea why you wouldn't use someone else's.